# low memory footprint for large arrays of different data types

Tags: delphi

I need to save physical memory while working with large arrays.  In my current code version I defined for each datatype a class like this

```
TMyData_01 = class 
      Const ID=$0001;  
      public 
      Data :  Integer;
      end;

TMyData_02 = class 
      Const ID=$0002;  
      public 
      Data :  String;
      end;
TMyData_03 = class 
      Const ID=$0003;  
      public 
      Data :  TDateTime;
      Index : Integer;
      end;
TMyData_04 = class 
  Const ID=$0004;  
  public 
  Data :  TDateTime;
  Value : Real;
  end;
    ...
```

I have  ~ 50 different basic class types and a few combination of these classes.

```
   MyCombinedData = class 
      Const ID=$0002;  
      public 
      Data_1 :  TMyData_01;
      Data_2 :  TMyData_02;
      Data_3 :  TMyData_03;
      Data_4 :  TMyData_04;
      end;
```

In the current code version I can read and write my data into these many class types and  run list of all these classes as Items inside a list/array.

But now I'm running in out of memory problems because my approach is ineffective
as each class type consumes 16 Byte for access + additional bytes for the data itself.

Furthermore if in a combined class not all subclasses are filled up with data
I created with this static appoach a lot of not effectivly used memory space.

- MyCombinedData[1] has data in subclass  1,2,3
- MyCombinedData[2] has data in subclass  2,3
- MyCombinedData[3] has data in subclass  1,2,3,4
- MyCombinedData[4] has data in subclass  2,3,4
- ..........

Any better approach in Delphi to store different data with a lower memory foot print ?

Comment: Very hard to give specific advice. Often algorithmic approaches are needed for such problems. Sometimes data structure design. Sometimes whole app redesign needed. Sometimes enough to make app large address aware. Perhaps 64 bit solves the problem. We don't even know the problem yet. Could even be memory fragmentation. Don't try to solve problems until you understand them.

Comment: You may be on the wrong track if the payload is very large compared to the overhead.

Comment: I'm looking for a data container,   just pass INDEX and CLASS_TYPEID and bytes to this storeage,   read back with INDEX from container I get Data as Bytes and TYPEID. Based on TYPEID I know how to convert these data to the correct data format ( string, INT, Real, dateTime,  ......)    or any other effectiv solution (any modern language feature from delphi for this issue)

Comment: Nobody can tell you what to do from this sparse information.

Comment: can attriubute work like fieldnames of a database table ?   http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/de/Attribute_zur_Laufzeit_extrahieren

Comment: Well, a database table can. Is this related with this questiıon?

Comment: Use records instead of classes. Allocate memory for those records using New() and deallocate using Dispose(). Store only the pointer for those records in your array. If your array is heterogeneous, add a TypeID field (byte) as the first field of your records, so you can always query it for its type. Besides that, sometimes you can also use AnsiString instead of String (if you are sure that AnsiString can hold your string data without Unicode issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this (if lower memory usage is more important than code simplicity):

```
const
  MaxBufferSize = 16; // the largest size you actually need, in this example sizeof(TMyData_04)...

type
  TMyData = packed record
    TypeID: Byte;
    Buffer: array[0..MaxBufferSize-1] of Byte;
  end;

  PMyData_01 = ^TMyData_01;
  TMyData_01 = packed record
    Data: Integer;
  end;

  PMyData_02 = ^TMyData_02; 
  TMyData_02 = packed record 
    Data: String;
  end;

  PMyData_03 = ^TMyData_03;
  TMyData_03 = packed record
    Data: TDateTime;
    Index: Integer;
  end;

  PMyData_04 = ^TMyData_04;
  TMyData_04 = packed record
    Data: TDateTime;
    Value: Real;
  end;

  ...
```

Then, you can allocate an array of `TMyData` instances to the needed length, and call `System.Initialize()` to initialize any items that contain compiler-managed data types:

```
var
  Arr: array of TMyData;

SetLength(Arr, ...);

//...

Arr[Index].TypeID := $01;
System.Initialize(PMyData_01(@Arr[Index].Buffer)^);
// populate PMyData_01(@Arr[Index].Buffer)^ fields as needed...

// and so on ...
```

Don't forget to call `System.Finalize()` on the items before deallocating the array, to avoid any memory leaks:

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
  begin
    case Arr[I].TypeID of
      $01: System.Finalize(PMyData_01(@Arr[i].Buffer)^);
      $02: System.Finalize(PMyData_02(@Arr[i].Buffer)^);
      $03: System.Finalize(PMyData_03(@Arr[i].Buffer)^);
      $04: System.Finalize(PMyData_04(@Arr[i].Buffer)^);
      // and so on ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Not ideal, but it is functional...

---

With a little bit of Generics trickery, you can cleanup the code a bit:

```
const
  MaxBufferSize = 16; // the largest size you actually need, in this example sizeof(TMyData_04)...

type
  TMyDataHelper<T: record> = record
    type PtrType = ^T;
    class function GetDataTypeID: Byte; static;
  end;

  TMyData = packed record
    TypeID: Byte;
    Buffer: array[0..MaxBufferSize-1] of Byte;
    procedure InitializeBuffer<T: record>;
    procedure FinalizeBuffer;
    procedure SetBufferData<T: record>(const NewData: T);
    function BufferAs<T: record>: TMyDataHelper<T>.PtrType;
  end;

  TMyData_01 = packed record
    Data: Integer;
  end;

  TMyData_02 = packed record
    Data: String;
  end;

  TMyData_03 = packed record
    Data: TDateTime;
    Index: Integer;
  end;

  TMyData_04 = packed record
    Data: TDateTime;
    Value: Real;
  end;

  // and so on ...

class function TMyDataHelper<T>.GetDataTypeID: Byte;
begin
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TMyData_01) then
    Result := $01
  else
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TMyData_02) then
    Result := $02
  else
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TMyData_03) then
    Result := $03
  else
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(TMyData_04) then
    Result := $04
  // and so on ...
  else
    Result := $00;
end;

procedure TMyData.InitializeBuffer<T>;
var
  LTypeID: Byte;
begin
  LTypeID := TMyDataHelper<T>.GetDataTypeID;
  if TypeID <> LTypeID then
  begin
    FinalizeBuffer;
    System.Initialize(BufferAs<T>^);
    TypeID := LTypeID;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyData.FinalizeBuffer;
begin
  case TypeID of
    $01: Finalize(BufferAs<TMyData_01>^);
    $02: Finalize(BufferAs<TMyData_02>^);
    $03: Finalize(BufferAs<TMyData_03>^);
    $04: Finalize(BufferAs<TMyData_04>^);
    // and so on ...
  else
    FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), $00);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyData.SetBufferData<T>(const NewData: T);
begin
  InitializeBuffer<T>;
  BufferAs<T>^ := NewData;
end;

function TMyData.BufferAs<T>: TMyDataHelper<T>.PtrType;
begin
  Result := TMyDataHelper<T>.PtrType(@Buffer);
end;
```

```
var
  Arr: array of TMyData;

SetLength(Arr, ...);
FillChar(Arr[0], Length(Arr)*SizeOf(TMyData), $0);

//...

Arr[Index].InitializeBuffer<TMyData_01>;
populate Arr[Index].BufferAs<TMyData_01>^ fields as needed...
or:
Arr[Index].SetBufferData<TMyData_01>(...);

// and so on ...
```

```
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    Arr[I].FinalizeBuffer;
end;
```